# How to render conditional with classNames with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use `classNames` to replace the conditional below in one line.

My problem is that i am not sure what is the right way to write the code because of the `div` etc...

I have the codes below :

## conditional

```
const { pageTitle, removeTitle = false } = props;   # destructuring

let result;

if(removeTitle){
  result = <div className="header-without-title">{pageTitle}</div>;
} else {
  result = <div className="header-with-title">{pageTitle}</div>;
}

return (<div className="result-title">{result});

};
```

If the `div` did not exist, i could write something like this...

```
const result = classNames({"header-without-title": removeTitle, "header-title": !removeTitle});
```

But i am not sure now that I have the `div` , I would appreciate some help here...

## A solution outside of `JSX` would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (
    <div className="result-title">
        <div className={`header-${removeTitle ? 'without-title' : 'with-title'}`}>{pageTitle}</div>
    </div>
);
```

or with use https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

```
return (
    <div className="result-title">
        <div className={classNames({ 'header-without-title': removeTitle, 'header-with-title': !removeTitle })}>
            {pageTitle}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

EDIT:
A solution outside of JSX

```
const result = (
    <div className={classNames({ 'header-without-title': removeTitle, 'header-with-title': !removeTitle })}>
        {pageTitle}
    </div>
);

return (
    <div className="result-title">
        {result}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, how would i write outside of the `JSX`?

Comment: `const result = classNames({ 'header-without-title': removeTitle, 'header-with-title': !removeTitle });` and use `<div className={result}>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just inline classNames function

```
const { pageTitle, removeTitle = false } = props;

const result = classNames({"header-without-title": removeTitle, "header-title": !removeTitle});

return (
  <div className="result-title">
    <div className={result}>
      {pageTitle}
    </div>
  </div>);
);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, how would i write the solution outside of the `JSX`

Comment: @JohnD I changed the code to move the classNames call into a variable and then load that variable into your div

Answer (score 0):

**There are several answers to this. Depends of each case**

Ternary between two classes in React:

```
<div className={`header-${removeTitle ? 'without-title' : 'with-title'}`}>
```

Ternary between class or null in React Javascript:

```
<div className={removeTitle ? 'without-title' : null}>
```

Ternary between render class or not in React Javascript and Typescript:

```
<div className={...(removeTitle ? { className: 'without-title' } : {})}>
```